# Yii HAS_MANY with some fixed values

Tags: php, yii

i have two models. Batch and Subject. The relation between them are Batch HAS_MANY Subjects. The problem is that three subject are MUST and for all batches. How can i implement this fixed values (the three subjects) in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to store the 3 default subjects in the database, you could write a function that returns the default subjects combined with any subjects that are actually related to the Batch object.

Assuming your relation is called 'subjects':

```
class Batch extends CActiveRecord
{
  ...
  public function getAllSubjects()
  {
    $subject1 = new Subject;
    ...
    $subject2 = new Subject;
    ...
    $subject3 = new Subject;
    ...
    return array($subject1, $subject2, $subject3) + $this->subjects;
  }
```

The limitation is that you can't reference the default subjects in database criteria, and you have to make sure to use `$model->allSubjects` instead of `$model->subjects`

Answer (score 0):

With a custom Validator. This should work, though it's untested.

```
class RelatedObjAttrRangeValidator extends CValidator {
  public $relationName;
  public $relatedObjectAttributeName;
  public $relatedObjectValues = array();

  public function validateAttribute($object, $attribute) {
    if(!$this->relationName) {
      $this->relationName = $attribute;
    }
    if(!$this->relatedObjectAttributeName || !count($this->relatedObjectValues)) {
      throw new CException("Misconfigured Validator!");
    }

    $relatedObjects = $object->getRelated($this->relationName);
    if(is_array($relatedObjects)) {
      $unmatched = array_values($this->relatedObjectValues);
      $attr = $this->relatedObjectAttributeName;
      foreach($relatedObjects as $relObj) {
        $val = $relObj->$attr;
        $idx = array_search($val, $unmatched);
        if($idx !== -1) {
          unset($unmatched[$idx]);
        }
        if(!count($unmatched)) {
          break;
        }
      }
      if(count($unmatched)) {
        $object->addError($attribute, $this->message);
      }
    } else {
      throw new CException(Yii::t('error', 'Relation {rel} in model {model} is not an array!', array(
        '{rel}' => $this->relationName,
        '{model}' => get_class($model),
      ));
    }
  }
}

class Batch extends CActiveRecord {
  public function rules() {
    return array(
      array('subjects', 'RelatedObjAttrRangeValidator', 
        'relatedObjectAttributeName' => 'ID',
        'relatedObjectValues' => array("required_id_1", "required_id_2", "required_id_3"),
        'message' => "One or more required Subjects are missing",
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not i wanted.i think its problem with my question. Suppose i have a $batchModel. then $batchModel->subjects must contain three preconfigured subjects + subjects that is related to the batch in the database. Even if there is no subject for a batch in the DB , ithe subjects attribute must contains three subects. Hope you got my question and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Yes, this validator would ensure that those specific subjects are included, but it doesn't include them automagically - that's not the validator's job. You could use the model's `afterSave()` function to check and include the additional subjects if they're missing.

Comment: ok.thanks. thats a good solution. I wonder is there any way the three subjects are not stored in the DB and they are hard-coded in the app. ( so that i can remove the redundant db entries since these subjects are common and same for all batches)